Libreoffice: Exit mail merge preview mode
I have made a mailmerge document. It looks like this:

When I click > it previews the document with the first element:

This is great, but how do I go back?
I have tried manually entering -1 or 0 in the mail merge element box. I tried leaving it empty. I tried CTRL-Z. None of those work.
I have the feeling that clicking > takes me from design mode into preview mode, and I just want to go back.
I have the feeling I am missing something obvious that is staring in my face.

Select Field Names from the View menu or press Command+F9.
